# Move Chrome window to right and current excel to left

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have a code to perform data entry from an excel sheet to a website which opens in google chrome. The code is working absolutely fine. I just want both the excel and chrome windows positioned on top side by side while macro is running. The excel window gets positioned to left perfectly however there is no impact on chrome window. I couldn't figure out the solution after googling a lot. Chrome and data entry is being controlled by Selenium.

```
'This part has code to import window resizing functions.
Private Type RECT
  Left As Long
  Top As Long
  Right As Long
  Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function MoveWindow Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, _
    ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal bRepaint As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Sub Selenuim_Upload()

Dim test1 As Long, test2 As Long
test1 = Timer

Dim obj As New WebDriver

obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.Get "https://csa.xyz.com/"
obj.FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlUserProfile").SendKeys ("Collector")
obj.FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_login").Click
obj.Get "https://csa.xyz.com/Collector_view.aspx/Default.aspx/"


'------------------------------------------------------------------------
' This part calculates window sizes and moves Excel window to left and IE window to right.
  Dim hWnd As Long
  Dim R As RECT, LW As RECT, RW As RECT

  'Get the size of the deskop
  If GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow, R) = 0 Then Exit Sub
  'Calculate the left and right side
  LW = R
  LW.Right = R.Left + (R.Right - R.Left) / 2
  RW = R
  RW.Left = R.Right - (R.Right - R.Left) / 2

  'Move Excel to the left
  hWnd = FindWindow("XLMAIN", vbEmpty)
  With LW
    MoveWindow hWnd, .Left, .Top, .Right - .Left, .Bottom - .Top, True
  End With
  BringWindowToTop hWnd

  'Move Chrome to the right
  hWnd = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", vbEmpty)
  With RW
    MoveWindow hWnd, .Left, .Top, .Right - .Left, .Bottom - .Top, True
  End With
  BringWindowToTop hWnd
'------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Select Invoice Number in Serch By box
obj.FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSearch").SendKeys ("Inv Number")

Range("A1").Select

'REST OF THE CODE CONTINUES FROM HERE
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your chrome window name is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Zac Yes "Chrome_WidgetWin_1" is the class name i got using WinID and saw in other developers codes. Is there other way to check window name?

Comment: Does any have fix for this problem? I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Do you get a value in `hWnd` when you try to find **Chrome_WidgetWin_1**? Make sure to clear `hWnd` before you attempt to get the `hWnd` for chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. Thanks to this thread [link](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1693252) . I used winlister (by nirsoft) to find the window title of that website that the macro was opening. Then replaced that with vbEmpty in  `hWnd = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", vbEmpty)` so the final line of code is like `hWnd = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", "https://csa.xyz.com/Collector_view.aspx/Default.aspx/ - Google Chrome")` .

Now the code is able to arrange both excel and chrome window side by side.